# How to write resolver for my query with Spring GraphQL

Tags: spring, graphql, spring-graphql

I need help in writing resolver for my GraphQL query with Spring.

problem is that each of the objects you see here are being passed from different API and I need to combine them with defined dependency. Since Graphql automatically calls instance api for each customer, I am not sure how to write resolver which can filter customers based on certain instance name

Here is my schema query and schema.graphqls

```
  customers(filter: {tenant: {instance: {instanceName: "ABC"}}}){
    tenants{
      tenantId
      instance{
        instanceName
      }
    }
  }
}

schema

type Customer{
    customerName: String
    tenants: [Tenant]
}

type Tenant{
    tenantId: ID
    instance: Instance
}

type Instance{
    instanceId: ID
    instanceName: String
}

type Query{
    customers(filter: CustomerFilterInput): [Customer]
}

input CustomerFilterInput{
    customerName: String
    tenant: TenantInput
}

input TenantInput{
    tenantId: String
    instance: InstanceInput
}

input InstanceInput{
    instanceName: String
    instanceId: String
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can you share your schema.graphqls file?

Comment: @JulioCésarEstravis Updated schema in question